# RDD basics about partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, distributed-computing, partitioning, rdd

I am reading [Spark: RDD operations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) and I am executing:

```
In [7]: lines = sc.textFile("data")

In [8]: lines.getNumPartitions()
Out[8]: 1000

In [9]: lineLengths = lines.map(lambda s: len(s))

In [10]: lineLengths.getNumPartitions()
Out[10]: 1000

In [11]: len(lineLengths.collect())
Out[11]: 508524
```

but I would expect that my dataset gets split in parts, how many? As the number of partitions, i.e. 1000.

Then the `map()` would run on every partition and return a *local* result (which then should be reduced), but if this is the case I would expect `lineLenghts` which is a list of numbers, to have length *equal* to the #partitions, which is not the case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(lineLengths.collect())` or `lineLengths.count()` tells you the number of rows in your rdd. `lineLengths.getNumPartitions()`, as you noted, is the number of partitions your rdd is distributed over. Each partition of the rdd contains many rows of the dataframe.